# where to put % sign correctly in a sql like query?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
ResultSet data = Db.db.search("select (flavour) from doenets where flavour like = '"+name+"%' ");
```

i think there is something wrong with this `like query` i tried replacing the position of `% sign` but didn't work can someone tell me `where to put` 
the `%` sign i want to get `simmilar words` begin with the `name`

Comment: % is used as a wildcard for any number of characters. Typically like '%abc%' to find strings with abc somewhere, (first, middle or last.)

Comment: This is prone to SQL injection. Use placeholders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The position of the `%` sign is ok.  What you need to do is remove the equals `=` sign.  It should simply be:

```
... where flavour like 'abc%'
```

And you would be better off using parameter binding instead of concatenating the values directly in the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to remove the "=" after the LIKE. The rest is correct.